# Complex Rails Routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, rails-routing

I would like to do something like github has with nested urls, and like [How do I route user profile URLs to skip the controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1863292/how-do-i-route-user-profile-urls-to-skip-the-controller) but not really sure how to go on with it.

For example, looking at a commit they have: ':user/:repo/commit/:sha', with the controller being commit. How would I replicate this type of nested resource?

thank you :)

Comment: What exactly is the problem that you are having? What have you tried and what didn't work? If you want the same route as github is using then just use that same route.

Comment: I wanted to be able to have nested resources within that, and figured out that I could do it with
  map.with_options :path_prefix => '/:user' do ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If commit is a RESTful controller that uses :sha instead of an id to find records. You could do this instead:

```
map.resource :commits, :path_prefix => ':user/:repo', :as => 'commit'
```

It will create the standard RESTful routes that look like `http://yoursite.tld/:user/:repo/commit/:id`

Again, if you'll never be translating the id portion in the url to a commit id, then there's no reason you can't use it as a :sha value.

example:

```
class CommitController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @commit = Commit.find(:first, :conditions => {:sha => params[:id]})
  end
  ...
end
```

You may also want to over ride to_param in the commit model to return the sha value.

```
class Commt < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  def to_param
    sha
  end
end
```

So that now `link_to commit_url(@commit, :user => current_user, :repo => @repo)` will provide a url that matches your scheme.

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
map.connect ':user/:repo/commit/:sha', :action => :index
```

Or use `map.resource` instead of `map.connect` if you need a RESTful route.

In the controller, the URL information can be retrieved from params, for example `params[:user]` returns the username.

Answer (score 0):

You can name your routes as you like, and specify which controllers and actions you'd like to use them with.

For example, you might have:

```
map.connect ':user/:repo/commit/:sha', :controller => 'transactions', :action => 'commit'
```

This would send the request to the 'commit' method in 'transactions' controller.

The other variables can then be accessed in your controller using params:

```
@user = User.find(params[:user])
@repo = Repo.find(params[:repo])
```